# NetBSD install, configure network, stuck at the command /sbin/ifconfig fwip0 media error: ifconfig SIOCGIFMEDIA: inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: system-installation, bsd, ifconfig, netbsd

I'm in NetBSD installation process, when configuring network, I'm stuck in this command and there is no way out of it:

```
Status: Command failed
Command: /sbin/ifconfig fwip0 media
Hi enter to continue
```

When I hit enter, I'm asked for a net media type:

```
Net media type []:
```

Anything that I enter, returns the following error message, even when I enter "autoselect" the error message appears again and again without getting out of the process:

```
---------------------------------------------
ifconfig: SIOCGIFMEDIA: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

The screenshots are shown below:

[image]

When hit Ctrl+z and then type ifconfig, I receive the following data for fwip0 device:

[image]

Actually, before I run into above mentioned issue, I configured another device (bge0) which worked fine.

Therefore, bge0 worked fine, but fwip0 is stuck and I cannot get out of installation process. Can anybody help. I cannot use that computer and I'm posting this question with somebody else's machine!

Answer (score 2):

I run into a similar problem in the past which I solved by setting the media type to `none`.

Comment: I tried many words, but unfortunately didn't try "none" I wish I had tried

Comment: Since firewire doesn't really have a "media" interface, `none` is probably the only valid media type to use with `fwip` interfaces (though `manual` might also work).  See the fine manual `ifmedia(4)` for a bit more info.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the firewire (`fwip`) interface is causing issues, but two things you might try, either of which should help:

1. Go into the BIOS setup and disable the firewire interface
2. Hit space to interrupt the NetBSD boot, then use `boot -c` to enter [userconf](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?userconf%20%20NetBSD-7.0) at which point you should be able to `disable fwip0` and then `quit` to continue the boot

Comment: Actually, I pressed "Ctrl+z" and then typed "ps" there was a process named "sysinst" so I typed "kill [process ID of sysinst]" and got out of installation process. I'm formatting the disk and I'm going to start installation from scratch again. This time I will not try to configure the firewire (fwip0).

Comment: I started installation process again, and I didn't configure firewire (fwip0). Everything is fine now and NetBSD is being installed without problem.

Comment: Indeed it is best to avoid trying to configure device drivers that are not needed.